# What was wrong with this question and what could I have done better?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, unclear

I wrote this question on how to do something in PHP. It was marked as bad and closed. What's wrong with it and what could I have done better on it?

*[How Do I Pull A PHP Variable From SQL Count Up and Update The Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72047514/how-do-i-pull-a-php-variable-from-sql-count-up-and-update-the-database)*

Comment: i rather than s in bind_param first argument. Is this any more than a typo?

Comment: Mini-Feedback, but I find the Title already very difficult to read with all (except 1) Words Capitalized, I need to read it at least 5 times to *hopefully* (?) understand it, maybe "better" would be: "**How do I pull up a PHP Variable from SQL Count and update the Database?**" which reads more naturally, ... if I'm correct that "Up" refers to "pull up" and not to "Count Up"...

Comment: I'm a simple meta-hound.  I see a post about someone wanting to learn how to improve, I upvote it.

Comment: @Makoto: you and me both. This behavior should be encouraged

Comment: [Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28computer_science%29), [count](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/count#Noun), and [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) are all common nouns (unless you use a hundred-year-old version of English—some parts of the world haven't updated yet).

Comment: @PeterMortensen BuT SaW cAsE iS mUcH mOrE aTtEnTiOn GrAbBiNg :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you don't want the attention of assassins though.

Answer (score 21):

Asking the same thing in the title and in the body of the question usually makes the question more likely to be well received.

In the case of the linked question title asks about some DB manipulation (presumably "increment field value") but body of the question shows problem with printing some value that can't be converted to string. This makes it unlikely for future visitors to find the question for problem they are facing and makes it harder to provide an answer for a single problem. Thus, the question was closed as "Add details and clarify the problem being solved", but also could have been closed as "resolved in a manner not likely to help future visitors".

To improve the question you could:

- figure out what you want to get answered and make sure that the title and the code in the question matches that: printing result of SQL query is very unlikely needed to increment value in the DB, so it could be removed if title reflects your need; changing title to match "can't print result of SQL query" error message and showing simple SQL query without extra code would be the other option.
- make sure code is [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Creating one for the question in the title would eliminate the error present in the body.
- Check how other questions format the title and follow that, review question (or at least the title) for matching what you wanted to write. The current title "How Do I Pull A PHP Variable From SQL Count Up and Update The Database?" has first letter upper-cased which is very unusual for SO; "Up" seem to be in a wrong place; SQL generally does not have "PHP variables" so maybe "Read value from SQL" would better align with what you needed (also rewriting the title to "Increment value in SQL" would be my choice).

Answer (score 0):

When I read it I'm not too sure what answer you're looking for, how to fix your code or a better working solution?

If the former, what have you done so far to try and fix it? what have you researched, what did you find out? what worked? what didn't work? Could you have reduced the amount of code you included to create a minimal example?

If the latter, what about your current solution do you not like that you would be looking to avoid? and again, what have you researched etc. How do you define "good"? What attributes are you looking to prioritize?